# Mocking non-class methods in c++

Tags: c++, unit-testing

I am trying to refactor code in a legacy application and ran into a situation where the code looks something like this

```
namespace DB
{
    void GetDataBase(IDataBase** db);
}
```

There are a lot of different places that this gets called from, and I want to test those methods but replace the result returned. Is there a certain design I can use to get this mocked correctly?

what I have is this but it doesn't seem like a good way to go, though it works

```
namespace DB
{
    void GetDataBase(IDataBase** db);
    void SetTestDataBase(IDataBase* db);
}
```

There are a lot of other similar situations and I would love to get some thoughts on how this can be improved.

Comment: Side note, but why in the world wouldn't this method be either `IDataBase * GetDataBase();` or `IDataBase & GetDataBase();`?

Comment: Fun stuff. Old c++ code so not really sure. Actually, most methods return error codes and return whatever is intended through parameters this way. Also, my guess is that this was done to get performance increases when RVO was not implemented or could not be used. take a look at this http://choorucode.com/2010/10/21/c-return-value-versus-output-parameter/

Comment: I see... in that case, at least `void GetDataBase(IDataBase *&);` would make more sense (IMO). But I understand dealing with legacy codebases. I was just curious.

Comment: @randomThought The best hints I found are at [google mock cookbook](https://code.google.com/p/googlemock/wiki/CookBook#Mocking_Free_Functions). But that would require to change a lot of your client code I'd guess.

Comment: @randomThought Perf comparison link is: http://codeyarns.com/2010/10/21/c-return-value-versus-output-parameter/

Answer (score 1):

The way you suggested is OK, but it pollutes the testing code and you will probably need more then one method like this. Also note that it might not work if there are static variables that are initiated and use this function.

What i suggest doing is either one of the two -

1. Clean the code, this is not a complicated function with lots of dependencies, you can easily change it into a simple factory call. To avoid going over all the functions that use it, you can create a macro that does it for you. The factory can then use an #ifndef statement to determine weather to take your mock or the real code. (compile the testing code with the define statement and the production code without it)
2. You can replace the implementation at linkage time. When compiling the production code, link it with the real implementation; but when you compile the test, link it with your mock to return an object of your liking.

Both ways make sure that no static methods that are called before the main are using the get method you want to mock.